# Using soto-cognito-authentication-kit

Tags: ios, amazon-cognito, soto

I need to implement native authentication with AWS Cognito and I am trying to use https://github.com/adam-fowler/soto-cognito-authentication-kit in my iOS App (client side).

I am struggling with the usage of the `CognitoAuthenticatable` object for starting a username/password auth.

Here is my code:

```
class LoginHandler {
    func handleLogin(username: String, password: String) {
        var eventLoopGroup = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 1)

        let data = AWSCognitoContext()
        let response = self.authenticatable.authenticate(
            username: username,
            password: password,
            requireAuthenticatedClient: false,
            clientMetadata: nil,
            context: data,
            on: eventLoopGroup.next()
        )

        response.flatMap { response in
            // use response object
        }
    }
}

class AWSCognitoContext: CognitoContextData {
    var contextData: CognitoIdentityProvider.ContextDataType? {
        return CognitoIdentityProvider.ContextDataType(
            httpHeaders: [],
            ipAddress: "",
            serverName: "",
            serverPath: "")
    }
}
```

The `authenticate` method is supposed to return `EventLoopFuture<CognitoAuthenticateResponse>`

1. How to handle the response of the `authenticate` method? I am getting the error `Generic parameter 'NewValue' could not be inferred`
2. How to construct the `CognitoContextData` object. I just want to use the default values for AWS server location.

Answer (score 0):

The authenticate function returns immediately with the `EventLoopFuture<...>`. It is fulfilled at a later point with the result of the authenticate when it has completed. The `EventLoopFuture` object has a number of ways to process this results. The simplest is `whenComplete`. You could do the following

```swift
response.whenComplete { result in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        process error ...
    case .success(let response):
        process authenticate response
    }
}
```

You would use `map` if you want to process the response object. eg

```swift
response.map { response -> NextObject in
    return CreateNextObject(from: response)
}
```

You would use `flatMap` if you want to chain multiple `EventLoopFutures` together. eg

```swift
response.flatMap { response -> EventLoopFuture<NextObject> in
    return CreateEventLoopFutureNextObject(from: response)
}
```

If you are having issues with `could not be inferred` errors it is always good to be explicit about what your closures are returning.

The swift nio docs will give you more info https://apple.github.io/swift-nio/docs/current/NIO/Classes/EventLoopFuture.html

The context data is to provide context to Cognito of where this authenticate request is coming from. This isn't really used when `requireAuthenticatedClient` is false. So providing an empty context is ok.

One other thing you shouldn't be creating an `EventLoopGroup` in your function. It is creating threads which can be time consuming and you then have to shutdown them down when all the processes are complete. You can use the eventLoopGroup here `authenticatable.configuration.cognitoIDP.eventLoopGroup`